# Set input fields value attribute from MYSQL database when selecting data from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I'm trying send select query and set the result as value attribute for different input fields, the query should be sent upon selecting a value from dropdown list. After doing some researches I found this can be reached through jQuery.

jQuery will send request to php file which contains my query and fetch result and then return values in json format. At this point everything is working great, my php file is working and return valid json data but I cannot get these data append in the input fields I have. Here is my script that should run the php file and return the results in json then append results in text fields.

[Check my code on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UeRRv/)

```
<script>
    var flight_destination = $('#destination).text();
    var flight_departure = $('#departure).text();
    var flight_arrival = $('#arrival).text();

    $('#flight_number').on('change', function() {

        var flight_info = $('#flight_number :selected').text();
        $.ajax({
            url: "getFlightData.php",
            type: "get",
            data: '?flight_number=$flight_number',
            success: function(data){ 
                var flight_destination = data[1];
                var flight_departure = data[2];
                var flight_arrival = data[3];   
            }
        }

        $('#destination').val(flight_destination);
        $('#departure').val(flight_departure);
        $('#arrival').val(flight_arrival);

    })
</script>
```

---

**getFlightData.php**

```
<?php
    include "dbConnect.php";
    $flight_number = $_GET['flight_number'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM flights WHERE flight_number='$flight_number'"); 
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
    {
        $row_data = array(
            'flight_number' => $row['flight_number'], 
            'destination' => $row['destination'],
            'departure' => $row['departure'],
            'arrival' => $row['arrival']
        );
        array_push($data, $row_data);
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

---

**GOOD NEWS**
A friends of mine helped me out with a syntax error in *data:* line. I did change it from `data:'flight_number='+$('#flight_number').val(),` to `data:{'flight_number':$('#flight_number').val()},`

In browser console window the json objects returned perfectly on change the drop down list value but still cannot append these objects to the input fields as value attribute

---

**Update 2**

Now I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/UeRRv/18/) Still the data returned in the browser's console window perfectly, but the only what appended in the first text field is [object]
[image: This is a screenshot] of the browser after selecting option from drop down list

---

**Update 3**
With great help and effort from @satyrwilder I'm now able to retrieve the first text field value. This is working version of the script snippet

```
$(function(){
    var flight_destination = $('#destination');
    var flight_departure = $('#departure');
    var flight_arrival = $('#arrival');
    var flight_number = $('#flight_number');

    $('#flight_number').on('change', function() {
       var flight_info = $('#flight_number :selected').text();
    $.ajax({
        url: "getFlightData.php",
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { 'flight_number' : flight_number.val() }
        })
    .done(function(data) {
        $("#destination").val(data[0].destination);
        $("#departure").text(data[0].departure).val(data[0].departure);
        $("#arrival").text(data[0].arrival).val(data[0].arrival);

    });
    });
});
```

I'm now looking forward to append the datetime-local values as well. I will keep this question updated regularly until it's 100% compelted

Comment: Change `data: '?flight_number=$flight_number',` to `data:'flight_number='+$('#flight_number').val(),`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I really appreciate it. Actually it doesn't work too.

Just for clarification
1- I have 1 text fields and 2 datetime-local fields.   

2- `getFlightData.php?flight_number=15463`  
returns flight info like this:-  
`[{"flight_number":"15463","destination":"Zurich","departure":"2014-02-21 04:37:00","arrival":"2014-02-28 07:17:00"}]`

Comment: okay, I might have misunderstood your question, sorry. I understand now. the `success` callback should go like this: success: function(data) { flight_destination.val(data[1]); ... }

Comment: I did but it still return nothing, also I did what @JorhelReyes mentioned in his answer and stills no luck

Comment: Are you sure that `data` is coming back to the client populated with a string of json and parsing it? If you are not sure, `success: function(data) { console.log(data); ...`

Comment: @satyrwilder The point where the results come from php file in json format is working just fine. Am not sure if this is what you're talking about or not. [Check the code here](http://jsfiddle.net/UeRRv/1/) It says uncaught syntax error in print.php:35

Comment: No, not quite. The PHP response should be emitting back to the client-side, which is where `success:function(data) {` fires. Add this to your code after the success callback: `error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log(jqXHR); console.error(textStatus); console.log(errorThrown); } `

Comment: @satyrwilder I appreciate your follow up very much :) actually a friend of mine helped me out with syntax error, he changed `data:'flight_number='+$('#flight_number').val(),` to `data:{'flight_number':$('#flight_number').val()},`  I checked the console window and json objects returned perfectly but stills cannot append them as value attribute for the input fields

Comment: Yeah I just saw that in your jsfiddle. Hold on I'm editing it now.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UeRRv/10/ -- find me in chat to discuss the fiddle if you need more help. (You should have a high enough rep to be able to chat, now ;) )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47368/discussion-between-satyrwilder-and-mmounirf)

Answer (score 0):

you must declare what type of data going to receive your inquiry.

`dataType: "json"`

```
$.ajax({
        url: "getFlightData.php",
        type: "get",
        data: '?flight_number=$flight_number',
        success: function(data){ ... },
        dataType: "json", //<--------- this 
});
```

[Documentation of $.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

---

And header from json in the start of you code php

For JSON:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

For JSON-P:

```
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still nothing returned in the input fields. I just put my script on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UeRRv/

Comment: the `data` property must be an object .ie `{flight_number: $flight_number}` and jquery takes care of the rest

Comment: Correction: the var data is object, not string, @peter your answer is true.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came to the final working code where everything is working perfectly. First I'd like to thank @satyrwilder for correcting my javascript part.

Here is the final code, which appends values from database into text and datatime-local fields using jquery + php

**getFlightDate.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include "dbConnect.php";
function datetime()
{
    return date( 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s', time());

}

$flight_number = $_GET['flight_number'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM flights WHERE flight_number='$flight_number'"); 
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{
$row_data = array(
    'flight_number' => $row['flight_number'], 
    'destination' => $row['destination'],
    'departure' => datetime($row['departure']),
    'arrival' => datetime($row['arrival'])
   );
  array_push($data, $row_data);

}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

**print.php**

```
<?php
include "dbConnect.php";
$flight_numbers = mysql_query("SELECT flight_number FROM flights"); 
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<select id="flight_number">
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($flight_numbers)) 
{
Print "<option>".$row['flight_number'] . "</option> ";
} 
?>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text" id="destination">
<input type="datetime-local" id="departure" />
<input type="datetime-local" id="arrival" />
<script>
$(function(){
    var flight_destination = $('#destination');
    var flight_departure = $('#departure');
    var flight_arrival = $('#arrival');
    var flight_number = $('#flight_number');

    $('#flight_number').on('change', function() {
       var flight_info = $('#flight_number :selected').text();
    $.ajax({
        url: "getFlightData.php",
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { 'flight_number' : flight_number.val() }
        })
    .done(function(data) {

        $("#destination").val(data[0].destination);
        $("#departure").text(data[0].departure).val(data[0].departure);
        $("#arrival").text(data[0].arrival).val(data[0].arrival);

    });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The trick was to change the datetime format before json_encode, because datetime-local input fields shows values in specific format which is `2014-12-05T08:30:59` -> `Y-m-d\TH:i:s`